# Quiero manipular muchas imágenes con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo alrededor de 200 imágenes y en pocas palabras quiero es mostrar una imagen en la web y cuando presione un botón muestre otra imagen aleatoriamente. Mis conocimientos sobre desarrollo web son básicos pero necesito resolver esto y quisiera un poco de ayuda,bueno realmente solo quiero que me digan si es posible hacerlo con javascript o necesito hacer algo externo y lo demás ya queda de mi parte investigarlo.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es intentar bro, y con muchísimas más ganas cuando eres nuevo, edita tu pregunta agregando el código que has intentado y en dónde tienes problemas.

Comment: Si JS permite hacer lo que quieres, pero no existe una única solución a tu problema. Puedes hacer fácilmente, teniendo una carpeta con dichas imágenes enumeradas tipo... img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg... Generar un numero aleatorio en JS e incrustar en el elemento de HTML deseado el codigo <img src="img"+aleatorio />.